# JAXB unmarshals XML into wrong subclass of an abstract type

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an abstract class **A** with two subclasses **B** and **C**. **A** looks like this:

```
@XmlTransient
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "A", propOrder = {
    "operation",
    "origin",
})
@XmlSeeAlso({B.class, C.class})
public abstract class A {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Operation operation;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Origin origin;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**B**:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "A") // root element is A for all subclasses
@XmlType(name = "B", propOrder = {
    "operation",
    "origin",
    "b",
})
public class B extends A {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String b;

    // getter and setter
}
```

**C**:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "A") // root element is A for all subclasses.
@XmlType(name = "C", propOrder = {
    "operation",
    "origin",
    "c",
})
public class C extends A {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String c;

    // getter and setter
}
```

How I create the JAXB context:

```
private static JAXBContext createJaxbContext() throws JAXBException {
    if(jaxbContext == null) {
        final ClassLoader classLoader = A.class.getClassLoader();
        final String contextPath = A.class.getPackage().getName();
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath, classLoader);
    }
    return jaxbContext;
}
```

When I pass in XML that conforms to the abstract class **A** but has property *b*, I expect JAXB to be able to unmarshal it into an object of type **B** (and the same for **C** if property *c* exists). What's currently happening is that it attempts to unmarshal all XML strings to **C** and only **C**, leading to a ClassCastException.

I've tried specifying the subclasses as types on the root node - i.e. something like:

```
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="C">
    <operation id="123" action="insert"/>
    <origin>
        <environment>DEV</environment>
        <instance>root</instance>
    </origin>
    <c>c value</c>
</A>
```

but this doesn't solve the problem.

What could I be doing wrong? Would appreciate any help :)

EDIT: if it helps this is the method used for unmarshalling

```
public static A toA(String xml) throws Exception{
    try {
      final Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = getJaxbContext().createUnmarshaller();
      final StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
      return (A) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      throw new Exception("Failed to unmarshal A " + "[" + e.toString() + "].");
    }
  }
```

And this is my ObjectFactory:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName A_QNAME = new QName("", "A");

    public ObjectFactory() {}

    public B createB() {
        return new B();
    }

    public C createC() {
        return new C();
    }

    public Operation createOperation() {
        return new Operation();
    }

    public Origin createOrigin() {
        return new Origin();
    }

    public A createA(A value) {
        return new JAXBElement<>(A_QNAME, A.class, null, value).getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can try to switch @XmlSeeAlso({C.class, B.class}), will the unmarshalling always result to C? Jaxb may not have 'unique' type to distinguish B vs C since the type of extension is String in both

Comment: could you post samples of the xmls you try to unmarshall?

Comment: @Jayr yes the unmarshalling always seems to happen on the second XmlSeeAlso (apologies - it was actually unmarshalling C, now that I've swapped the two it unmarshals B instead).

Comment: @mart updated the question with sample xml

Comment: @ledba did you ever fix this? Having the same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but it uses composition instead of inheritance. I am not sure if you have reasons that you need to extend the class.

I simplify class A so I dont have to create classes for origin and operation, but I believe you get the point (if not please let me know):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    // operation and origin stay the same

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "b", type = B.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "c", type = C.class),
    })
    protected Object bOrC;
}
```

Classes B and C would look something like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class B {

    @XmlValue
    private String value;
}
```

Instead of having Object in class A you could have an interface which both B and C would extend.

Then it would unmarshall fine for having `<c>` or `<b>` values:

```
<A xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!--<operation id="123" action="insert"/>-->
    <!--<origin>-->
        <!--<environment>DEV</environment>-->
        <!--<instance>root</instance>-->
    <!--</origin>-->
    <c>c value</c>
</A>
```